# issue with ASP.Net Linkbutton and CSS class (visited)

Tags: asp.net, css, linkbutton, visited

I have an asp.net (.Net Framework 4.0) page with a gridview in it which contains linkbuttons. I set the cssclass property of the linkbuttons to make sure, the Color of the text changes when the link is being clicked (visited). Unfortunately that doesn't work... when i click on the linkbutton, the Color changes, then the postback occures and when i go back to that page, the linkbutton has the original Color :-( (tested with IE10, in IE8 and Firefox the Color even changes to the standard-link Color - not the Color i set, it also changes back immediately).

I tried it with Asp:Hyperlink which works, but i have many pages in my web with linkbuttons and wanted to avoid changing every page...

This is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDetails" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("str_Betreff") %>'
CssClass="westsitelinkbutton" OnClick="lnkDetails_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is the css code:

```
.westsitelinkbutton a:visited
{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here is the code within "lnkDetails_Click":

```
Public Sub lnkDetails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

        Response.Redirect("mitarbeiter_gesendet_details.aspx?id=" & gvGesendeteObjekte.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        objFunctions.ShowAlert("fehler", ex.Message, ClientScript, Page)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this issue please?

Kind regards,

Sabrina

Comment: Did you use any skin file?

Comment: When you go back to the previous page, hit CTRL F5, make sure the browser is not caching the page.  If that refresh doesn't help, try using developer tools in IE, Chrome or Firefox and examine the link button and see if it has an class on it, usually the tools will tell you which class and where it is located as well.

Comment: @afzalulh - no, i didn't use any Skin file.

Comment: @Paritosh: I tried the developer Tools in IE10, when i use a css class, the tool recognizes the class and shows it with the Color i set... but it does not have any effect on the linkbutton :-(. Is it because of the Postback that there is no visited-state within a linkbutton?

Comment: Actually it most likely is because a LinkButton does not set the href property of the link to a page.  If you use a linkbutton and look at the source (HTML) in the browser it probably has the link's href property set to some javascript code, which is why it's not being flagged as visited, because the browser can't tell if you already visited the javascript code, it needs to be a page.  Can you try using a HyperLink control instead?  that one might work.

Comment: ok, i was afraid of that :-(. so it is generally not possible to set the visited style of a asp.net linkbutton via css?

Comment: if it has href set to javascript doesn't look it, as the browser needs a page url set to make sure it can track if you have visited it before.  otherwise you can maybe set a session variable when you hit the page the linkbutton links to, then when you return to the page where the linkbutton is in your code check if that variable is there, if so means you visited the page, via code change the color of the linkbutton.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Paritosh... i will change all linkbuttons to Hyperlinks.